# boost-1.55.0 undefined reference to `boost::thread::join() even after linking with the correct library

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, linker-errors

I get undefined symbol reference errors even after linking with the correct boost library:

```
undefined reference to `boost::thread::join()
undefined reference to `boost::thread::start_thread()
```

`nm libboost_thread.so -Cg|grep boost::thread::join` shows

```
000000000000ce00 T boost::thread::join_noexcept()
000000000000c1a0 T boost::thread::joinable() const
```

What happened to join() ?

Answer (score 2):

boost::thread::join() is an inline function now.

Your build system probably does not maintain dependencies on system headers and ends up linking object files compiled against an older version of boost. Do a full rebuild.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like we are linking with a 3rd party linbrary that was built against an older version of boost that the one we are linking against. Your answer helped me to find that.